# Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. But I have everything I need

Tags: post, django-csrf

I get Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
When I submit the form on the home.html page...

I have no idea why because I have the {% csrf_token %} in the form,

I have the right settings

I am using context_instance=RequestContext(request)

This is the form (it is in home.html):

```
<form method="post" action="/schedule/" >
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="text" name="course1" value="" maxlength="100" />
                <input type="text" name="course2" value="" maxlength="100" />
                <input type="text" name="course3" value="" maxlength="100" />
                <input type="text" name="course4" value="" maxlength="100" />
                <input type="text" name="course5" value="" maxlength="100" />
                <input type="text" name="course6" value="" maxlength="100" />
                <br />
                <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

This are my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from . import AllClasses
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.template import RequestContext
import datetime


def home(request):
    return render_to_response("src/home.html", {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
# Create your views here.

def schedule(request):
    c = {}
    subjects = []
    courses = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        subjects[0] = request.POST['course1']
        subjects[1] = request.POST['course2']
        subjects[2] = request.POST['course3']
        subjects[3] = request.POST['course4']
        subjects[4] = request.POST['course5']
        subjects[5] = request.POST['course6']

        for subject in subjects:
            courses.append(Course.objects.filter(subject=subject))
        c.update({'courses_inputed': courses})
    return render_to_response("src/weekataglancetest.html", c, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

Please help I've been stuck on this for so long!

Thanks very much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted my server and now it works!

Wished I would have done that sooner, I'm hungry now.